# How to check mapbound zoom level?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have arrayof LatLng for location and I have default zoom level to show result.
But I want apply this default zoom level if all location is displayable otherwise only then set zoom from google.maps.LatLngBounds();

And also it shows result in full zoom if there is only one result to show.
So how to check that.

Code as:

```
var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();   
for (i = 0; i < arrMarkers.length; i++) 
{
    bound.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(arrMarkers[i].getPosition().lat(), arrMarkers[i].getPosition().lng()));
                            }
   strDefaultLtLong = bound.getCenter();

var image = 'Images/star.png';
var mapOptions = {
                        center: strDefaultLtLong,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                        zoom: parseInt(strDefaultZoomLevel)

                 }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
this.map.fitBounds(bound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map.setZoom(<A NUMBER>);` to set the map zoom level after it was instantiated. Now, if the array has length = 1, you use one number/zoom. Otherwise, you use use the default level.

Comment: I have put that below `this.map.fitBounds(bound);` as `map.setZoom(parseInt(strDefaultZoomLevel));` but still it not working.. :-(